# Oauth 2.0 | Google Documentation for operations

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-client

**I am not able to find google documentation where all valid possible operation url per scope are mentioned?**

I am consuming google API, using oauth 2.0 by Httpclient ie without using google api client jar or dependency.

To fetch Users profile I set `emailId profile` in `scope` and made a get request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=XXX using HttpClient,this is working.

There is a [page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) where all scopes are mentioned but unable to find list of possible operations for particular scope.Please help me into this.Thanks!

Comment: Probably more relevant to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

On the [page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) describing scopes, if you click on the title of a scope section, say the Calendar API, you are brought to that API's [home page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview). From here you can got to the guides tab and follow the quick start for the language of your choice (which Google encourages since their client libraries tend to do a lot of the work for you), or go to the reference tab and view the available endpoints. From here you can send your access token as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#callinganapi)

As far as which scope applies to which endpoint, I assume view and read only scopes will probably only work for GET requests, while other manage scopes will probably encapsulate the other endpoints. Apart from that assumption, I don't know if Google has the scope exactly lined up with the endpoints they are valid for.